# Finding symbols and namespaces in Clojurescript

Tags: clojurescript

Is there an equivalent way in Clojurescript to get ns-map, ns-public etc and find what namespaces are available ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks there isn't, apart from using goog.globals via Javascript